# How to make a function that returns the positional value of a number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, math, numbers

I need to make a function that returns the value corresponding to its positional value.

Example:

positional value
Ten in 1234 returns 3
hundred in 1234 returns 2
1 unit of thousand, 2 hundred, 3 ten, 4 unit

I'd tried this:

```py
def positional_value(x):
  x=str(x)
  numbers=[]
  numbers.extend(x)
  numbers.reverse()
  for index,i in enumerate(numbers):
    if index==0:
      print(i) #so where x is 1234, Here I can get 4.
```

With what I tried I just can get the numbers by index. I thought that using a list with the positional values names (unit, ten, hundred, unit of thousand, ...) will help to describe each query to the function.

output example: when you print the function:

```py
1 unit of thousand
2 hundred
3 ten
4 unit
#and goes on when the number is bigger
```

Comment: Could you add an example of what you want the function to print when you pass it `1234`?

Comment: If you want a `function that returns the value corresponding to its positional value`, it seems like `positional_value` should take two arguments: the number and the position.

Comment: do you want to convert number to word ?

Comment: ^ (with the addition of a simple lookup table from strings `'hundereds", "thousands"`, etc. to the corresponding digit indices)

Comment: @Deepstop example added!

Comment: I dind't understand your question at first, sorry I made an update in my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def positional_value(x, pos):
    return x // (10**(pos-1)) % 10


NAMES = ["", "unit", "ten", "hundred", "thousand"]
for pos in range(4,0,-1):
    val = positional_value(1234,pos)
    if val!=0:
        print("%d %s" %(val, NAMES[pos]))
```

Comment: This will work adding the corresponding word to the `print(positional_value(1234,1))`

Comment: Edited to a more complete example. Obviously, you need to know your supported maximum, so you could extend it to have those words. Also, add sanity checks for wrong types, negative numbers, etc.

Answer (score 3):

A way to do it if you want the digits is:

```
def positional_value(x):
  numbers=[]
  v = x
  while v != 0:
    numbers.append(v%10)
    print(v%10)
    v = v // 10
    print(v)
  return numbers
```

But if you want the index of a specific number in your big number:

```
def positional_value(x, n):
  numbers=str(x)
  return numbers.find(str(n)) 

print(positional_value(1234, 2))
1
print(positional_value(1234, 4))
3
```

But if you want to look it backwards, reverse is ok

```
def positional_value(x, n):
  numbers=str(x)[::-1]
  return numbers.find(str(n)) 

print(positional_value(1234, 2))
2
print(positional_value(1234, 4))
0
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to accepted answer, but using the value as a string, rather than integer division.

```
def positional_values(x):
    positions = ['unit', 'ten', 'hundred', 'unit of thousand', 'ten-thousand',
                 'hundred-thousand', 'unit of million', ]
    for i, c in enumerate(str(x)):
        print(f"{int(c)}: {positions[len(str(x)) - i - 1]}")

positional_values(1234)

1: unit of thousand
2: hundred
3: ten
4: unit
```

Comment: It's a clean code, just need to be in a function and is perfect!

Comment: OK, updated into a function.